# whatever - Are these all noun clauses?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, subordinate-clauses

Are these all noun clauses? And what part of speech is *whatever* in each of them? Are they pronouns, determiners, or something else?

> 1. I'll take ***whatever you can give***.       (direct object)
> 2. Using ***whatever tools were available***, they accomplished much.   (direct object of the participle)
> 3. I am against prejudice in ***whatever form it takes***.  (object of the preposition)

Thanks!

Note: The post “whatever” as pure determiner?” did not answer my question, but instead created some of my confusion. Additionally, that post focused on adding the relative pronoun *that* to the noun clause. It did not focus on what the proper term for a noun clause is, along with the determiners and pronouns that are associated with them. See my own answer to my question in the answer section below.

Comment: (3) isn't the object of the preposition; it's the object of _takes_. And what do **you** think they are? Pronouns, determiners, or something else? And why?

Comment: (1) you can give whatever – So I would say that _whatever_ is a pronoun that functions as the direct object.
(2) whatever tools were available – So I would say that _whatever_ is a determiner. 
(3) it takes whatever form  – So I would say that _whatever_ is a determiner. 

You say (3) isn’t the object of the preposition? Isn’t “in whatever form it takes” a prepositional phrase that modifies _prejudice_? If it is, then “whatever form it takes” would seem to be a noun clause that is the object of the preposition “in.”

If they are pronouns and determiners, are they a certain kind?

Answer (score 1):

There are two sets of objects to be considered here, and it's easy to confuse them. 
The important thing to remember is that only noun phrases can be objects, but clauses can be noun phrases.

First, there are the *Wh*-clauses, all of which are object clauses (and therefore noun clauses):

- *whatever you can give* **is the direct object of** *take*
- *whatever tools were available* **is the direct object of** *using*
- *whatever form it takes* **is the object of the preposition** *in*

Second, the internal structures of the Wh-clauses themselves determine the function of *whatever*:

- in *whatever you can give*,
  *whatever* **is the direct object of** *give*.
- in *whatever tools were available*,
  *whatever* **modifies** *tools*;
  and the noun phrase *whatever tools* **is the subject of** *were available*.
- in *whatever form it takes*,
  *whatever* **modifies** *form*;
  and the noun phrase *whatever form* **is the direct object of** *takes*.

Answer (score 0):

I had come across a few sources that said *whatever* is a relative pronoun, and the poster on that other thread called *whatever* a relative determiner. Also, I thought I had seen examples of people calling these clauses *relative clauses*.

Now, after doing more research, I see that some people do call the clauses in my examples *relative clauses*, and they say that the clauses contain either the relative pronoun or the relative determiner *whatever*. While some do make a distinction and call them *free relative clauses*, others just call them *relative clauses*. Of course, most people just call them *noun clauses*.

People usually learn that a relative clause is an adjective clause and an adjective clause is a relative clause. The clauses in my example sentences clearly do not function as adjectives, so I was trying to figure out what I was missing.

If we call *whatever* a relative determiner and a relative pronoun, then it only makes sense to call these clauses *relative clauses*. But that sure creates a problem for the majority of people who learn that a relative clause functions as an adjective and a relative pronoun introduces a relative clause.

I now see that Oxford Dictionaries does list *whatever* as being a relative pronoun and determiner. Google uses Oxford in their search results, but they only list it as being a pronoun and determiner, and Merriam Webster lists it as being a pronoun and adjective.

In his answer, Mr. Lawler verified what I outlined in my original question and my added comment. Thank you! However, my real question was this: What do we call these things? My confusion was primarily caused by people using different terms for the same concepts. I hope this answer clears up some confusion for others. I now know what I will call them.

I will restate my analysis that I listed in my comment above. I simply reordered the words in the noun clause:

1. you can give *whatever* – *whatever* is a pronoun that functions as the direct object.
2. *whatever* tools were available – *whatever* is a determiner that modifies *tools*.
3. it takes *whatever* form  – *whatever* is a determiner that modifies *form*.

I now see that I can put “relative” in front of *pronoun* and *determiner* as long as I provide additional explanation.